# in Xcode SCM, how to ignore some runtime files while comitting to SVN?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

in Xcode SCM, how to ignore some runtime files while comitting to SVN?

Answer (score 2):

vi ~/.subversion/config
find  global-ignores in the config file, add the ignoring list below:

> global-ignores = *~.nib *.so *.pbxuser
>   *.mode *.perspective* *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store

find enable-auto-props, change into enable-auto-props = yes
in [auto-props] Section, add

> *.mode* = svn:mime-type=text/X-xcode
>
> *.pbxuser = svn:mime-type=text/X-xcode
>
> *.perspective* = svn:mime-type=text/X-xcode
>
> *.pbxproj = svn:mime-type=text/X-xcode